# How to get the ID from a route inside a Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

Is there a way to call the url with ID from an ajax?
Currently, I have an href file inside an Ajax. This href is inside a datatable and it will redirect to a different page.

Here's my Ajax code:

```js
{ data: "user_type_text" },
{
    data: "id",
    render: function (data, type, arr) {

        let approvebutton = ''
        if (arr.status == 0) {
            approvebutton = `
                <button data-id="${arr.id}" class="approve-user-button btn btn-link btn-info btn-just-icon btn-round">
                    <i title="Approve" class="material-icons">check</i>
                <div class="ripple-container"></div>
                </button>
                `
        }
        
        let url = '/sms-history/' + id;
       
        return `
        <a class="btn btn-link btn-success btn-just-icon btn-round" href="${url}" title="SMS History">
        <i class="material-icons">sms</i>
        <div class="ripple-container"></div>
        </a>`;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I set the href with `${url}`, where `url = '/sms-history/' + id;`. I'm trying to achieve this result: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/sms-history/10`, however, I'm getting an error "ID is not defined"

I do have 2 controllers for this (`UserController` and `SmshistoryController`) and 2 blade files (UserBlade `and` SMsBlade).

I assume that the ID that is from the `SMShistory` will automatically be read by my user ajax file. What am I doing wrong? can you please provide some insights?

Comment: There is no Ajax in your Ajax code. Please add at least the enclosing function so that the context of this code becomes clearer.

Comment: Also show the contents of `data`, `type`, and `arr`. You can use `console.log()` to print them out.

Answer (score 0):

Previous you define id on the button as follows `arr.id`. With that logic, i would assume the following would help.

```
let url = '/sms-history/' + arr.id;
```

Comment: arr.id is not the one that I'm trying to append but I get your idea. I modified the code and declared the ID. The link is now working fine, this is showing as http://127.0.0.1:8000/sms-history/3 the ID is now appended to the URL. The only problem now, its not redirecting properly and it is only showing me blank page.

Comment: Then you route in laravel must be broken what does the network tab show in your browser?

Comment: I'm not seeing any issues in the network tab. It's throwing 200 OK response.
Here's my route: `Route::get('/sms-history/{id}', 'SmsHistoryController@getView')->name('history');`

my controller:
` public function getView($id)
    {
       $smshistory = SmsOutboundsHistory::find($id);
        return view('history', compact('smshistory'));       
    }`

not really sure what's the problem here, route and controller looks fine to me

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solved this by adding a query inside the controller and edited the code in js.

```
render: function (id, data, type, arr){
               
                let url = '/sms-history/' + id;

<a class="btn btn-link btn-success btn-just-icon btn-round" href="${url}" title="SMS History">
                <i class="material-icons">sms</i>
                <div class="ripple-container"></div>
```